# dyld: Symbol not found: ___chkstk_darwin

Tags: xcode, xcode11

After upgrading Xcode to Version 11.1 (11A1027), my iOS app(MyApp) crashes in Xcode at the start of its running with the following runtime error:

dyld: Symbol not found: ___chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/xxxxxxxxxx/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

MacOS: Mojave 10.14.6 (18G103)
Xcode: 11.1 (11A1027)
Target Device: iPhone 6 Plus
Target Device iOS: 12.4.2

It does not have any issues in Xcode 10.3.
Any helps, comments will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've run into this same issue on a similar setup. Same Xcode version with an app targeting 12.4. Only difference for me is I'm targeting an iPhone 8. Feels like an issue with a mismatched SDK version somehow.

Comment: There is an update. I ran the same test against iPhone 6S with iOS 13.1.2, then there was no issues at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the problem. I generate my Xcode projects with CMake and for some reason CMake is having a very hard time setting the Base SDK option on the project.

[image: Bad Base SDK]

If I manually set the Base SDK to iOS it seems to build and run just fine

[image: Good Base SDK]

Comment: No sooner than I replied to your first comment, I found your answer. Thanks a lot for your answer. In the project's build settings in Xcode11, Architecture & Base SDK settings look all correct. Since I don't have used CMake, can I ask you how to apply your solution in CMake to Xcode11?

Comment: The problem on my end was that CMake wasn't properly setting this Base SDK property when it generated the Xcode project. The problem was the same with Xcode 10.3 but Xcode responded to the failure by reporting that it was unable to launch the app. If you're running into the same problem even though the Base SDK field was set correctly it seems we've run into the same problem from different angles :(

Comment: I have found the problem in Xcode11 settings. My project contains several static libraries those are also built during the target build. Somehow, after migrating Xcode from v10.3 to v11.1, the target iOS settings in the some (not all) library projects have been implicitly changed to iOS 13.1. That causes iOS SDK conflict  issues in regard to some runtime functions (i.e. chkstk_darwin). I had to manually search the "affected" library projects and change their target iOS settings back to 12.4. Then problem is solved in Xcode11. Thanks for your replies. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this issue born bug of XCODE version 13.2.1 .Then I down grade version xcode to 13.1 is can fix this issue I can run app os 12.x.x .

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I compiled a C program with a VLA on MacOS 10.15 and then ran it on 10.13. If this is why for you then use `malloc()` instead.

Comment: Setting the deployment target to 10.13 would fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because one of the libraries used by the app was built for newer iOS version. Changing the iOS deployment target to 12.2 fixed the crash.

[image]